# Ключи в двойных квадратных скобках

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Когда консолишь react synthetic event или proxy то в консоли отображается объект с какими-то непонятными ключами в двойных квадратных скобках, например [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это ?

Comment: Скорее всего обычные ключи, к которым разработчики не хотят, чтобы вы имели доступ. Своеобразная инкапсуляция.

Comment: Не соглашусь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174786/what-is-the-significance-of-the-double-brackets-for-the-prototype-property-i

Но у меня остался вопрос как это повторить самому ?

Comment: Это немного не то. Так в спецификации описываются внутренние свойства для реализации. А тут вы конкретно можете  увидеть это своими глазами. Создайте обычный Proxy-объект и посмотрите сами.

Comment: Как повторить самому? `let o = {"[[NameInSquareBrackets]]": "something"}; o["[[NameInSquareBrackets]]"] // => "something"` - пожалуйста.

Comment: @smellyshovel очень смешно)) Дело в том что свойства объектов с ключом в двойных кавычках доступны при обращении в родительский объект

Answer (score 0):

[[Свойство]] означает, что это Свойство есть в потенциале, но фактически, сейчас - его нет.

Например `[[Prototype]]`. Если обратиться к `object.Prototype` - то его нет, но в потенциале (в некоторых браузерах) к нему можно обратиться по ключу `__proto__`.

Цитата из [ECMAScript 8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2):

> This specification uses various internal properties to define the semantics of object values. These internal properties are not part of the ECMAScript language. They are defined by this specification purely for expository purposes. An implementation of ECMAScript must behave as if it produced and operated upon internal properties in the manner described here. The names of internal properties are enclosed in double square brackets [[ ]].